# Bug passing variables by reference

Tags: c, graph, reference

I have a rather simple issue. I wrote a computer code in C language that gets a graph in the form of an adjacency matrix where each edge in the graph has a number associated with it, a weight if you will.

if the weight of an edge is 0, then that edge does not exist. so for example if in the entry (1,2) in the adjacency matrix is 0, then we know vertex 1 is not connected to vertex 2.

So far so good. My problem is I'm trying to count how many edges are there, and I'm getting an unexpected value.

```
int **get_adjacency_matrix(int* num_of_vertices,int *num_of_edges)
{
    int i,j,k,**graph,rows=0;
    printf("Enter the number of vertices in your connected undirected graph:");
    scanf("%d",num_of_vertices);
    printf("\nVery important: I assume there are no parallel edges\n");
    rows=*num_of_vertices;
    graph=(int**)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
        graph[i]=(int*)malloc((rows-i)*sizeof(int));
    printf("Please Enter the upper triangular cost-adjacency matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<i;k++)
            printf("  "); //blank spaces for readability.
        for(j=0;j<rows-i;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&(graph[i][j]));
            if(graph[i][j]>0)
                (*num_of_edges)++; //edge found
        }
    }
    printf("*num_of_edges = %d",*num_of_edges);
    return graph;
}
```

This code does indeed print the correct result. But in my void main I wrote

```
void main()
{
    int **graph,num_of_vertices=0,num_of_edges=0,k;
    edge *edges_array;
    graph=get_adjacency_matrix(&num_of_vertices,&num_of_edges);
    printf("there are % edges.\n",num_of_edges);
}
```

and that line prints garbage. weirdly enough, the num_of_vertices variable is working correctly.

So inside the **get_adjacency_matrix program, my num_of_edges gets the correct value, but it returns the wrong value to the void main.

Why?

Comment: Btw `void main()` is bad; use `int main(void)` instead.

Comment: `printf("there are % edges.\n",num_of_edges);` has a faulty format specifier, should be `%d`.

Comment: Oh my god...That's so terrible to have missed that.

Comment: Most compilers on strict settings would have picked that up, I think.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** revised previous answer.

The statement

```
printf("there are % edges.\n",num_of_edges);
```

has a faulty format specifier, should be `%d`.

Comment: graph is a local variable in get_adjacency but i returned it, so it is "saved" if you will in the graph variable in main. regardless, my issue isnt with graph, its with num_of_edges